# Is SVCUTIL.exe broken or is it the supplier's WSDL?

Tags: wsdl, svcutil.exe

I am trying to use SVCUTIL from the SDK to generate the common types in several web services. When I try to generate code I get the errors (shown at the bottom)- these suggest the WSDL is broken. However, if I import the service in ServiceReferences Visual Studio does not complain. Is SVCUTIL broken?

The WSDLs are public and are:

http://test.wlr3.net/empws/services/WLR3AssuranceServices?wsdl
http://test.wlr3.net/empws/services/WLR3BillingServices?wsdl
http://test.wlr3.net/empws/services/WLR3DialogueServices?wsdl
http://test.wlr3.net/empws/services/WLR3FulfillmentServices?wsdl
http://test.wlr3.net/empws/services/WLR3InventoryServices?wsdl
http://test.wlr3.net/empws/services/WLR3InventoryOrderServices?wsdl
http://test.wlr3.net/empws/services/WLR3InventoryTroubleReportServices?wsdl
http://test.wlr3.net/empws/services/WLR3InventoryWorkItemServices?wsdl
http://test.wlr3.net/empws/services/WLR3IssueServices?wsdl
http://test.wlr3.net/empws/services/WLR3ReportingServices?wsdl
http://test.wlr3.net/empws/services/WLR3SecurityServices?wsdl

If you check these out you'll see a lot of common types and several namespaces. I've tried sending these to SVCUTIL to generate the code but it doesn't like the FulfillmentServices and the InventoryServices ones:

```
 Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.XmlSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Cannot import invalid schemas. Compilation on the XmlSchemaSet failed.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://imperatives.co.uk/V20']/wsdl:portType[@name='WLR3FulfilmentServices']

Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://imperatives.co.uk/V20']/wsdl:portType[@name='WLR3FulfilmentServices']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://imperatives.co.uk/V20']/wsdl:binding[@name='WLR3FulfillmentServicesHttpBinding']

Error: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://imperatives.co.uk/V20']/wsdl:binding[@name='WLR3FulfillmentServicesHttpBinding']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://imperatives.co.uk/V20']/wsdl:service[@name='WLR3FulfillmentServices']/wsdl:port[@name='WLR3FulfillmentServicesHttpPort']
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? The first one worked for me.

Comment: In this case it's targeting 3.5 as the library is shared. The WSDLs import into Visual Studio fine, it's the problem of getting the types out by using SVCUTIL

Comment: I should point out it's only the Inventory and Fulfillment WSDL's that seem to generate an error

Comment: I think I may have spotted the cause. There is an empty virtual base type 'Dto' in the types for InventoryServices and FulfilmentServices. It only appears in these two wsdls and they are the ones generating errors in SVCUTIL. The WSDL is valid so I think it's a bug. Will confirm if editing these out results in working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments to the question, there is a small difference in the two problem WSDLs. I compared these with older versions and found there is a type in these based on a virtual base type called "Dto".

This is applied to only two types - one in the Fulfillment Services and one in the Inventory Services, and these are also found in other WSDLs but without the base - the WSDL files are not consistent.

So I can exponerate SVCUTIL here and give the supplier a kick..

Thanks to John Saunders for looking at it